# How can I get my PC to detect my GPU

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, hardware-detection

I have built a new PC, in this I have got the following spec;

- i5 9400
- asrock h310cm-hdv/m.2 motherboard
- 8gb ram
- 550w PSU
- MSI GTX 970 4gb

But I have the following issue;

> When using the GPU, this does not detect at all

If I swap for my old 1050 2gb it detects fine so I know the PCIe slot doesn't have fault, plugging the 8 pin power to the 970 lights the LEDs on it, but GeForce experience cannot find the card

I have re-seated the GPU, I have turned on and off, I have changed bios settings to use PCIe main lane, changed GPU and that worked, drivers all installed for the motherboard

What could the issues be here? I am very much at a loss

Comment: Are you sure the graphics card is genuine? Compare your card with official images from MSI. Some people have encountered forged graphic cards where very old models were modified and sold as recent model. The old models are so old that GeForce experience does not support them.

Comment: Does anything show up in Device Manager?

Comment: @Robert - yes it's official

Comment: @Mokubai - nothing shows in device manager, I have scanned for hardware changes too

Comment: Are you sure the card is functional? Just because some LED lights turn on does not mean the card itself is functional

Comment: Then the card is dead, either the PCIE bus chip is fried or something else is wrong with the onboard power supply.

Comment: @Mokubai - it saddens me that at this point, I have no other ideas than to believe you are right :S

Comment: Check if you have your windows up to date, had the same issue once and having an up to date windows instalation usb solved my problem